# How to restart nodejs process

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, mocha.js, nodes

Hi guy really thanks for clicked this question. Let me go through what i have done and what i tried and what my scenario.

Question: How can i restart my nodejs application without exiting process? Because if i use the process.exit it will exit my mocha test too. Which is not i want. I just wanted to restart nodejs application.

## The way i run my mocha test

```
mocha test/main.js
```

Really appreciate for who can help me with this.

## Scenario

1. i am writing automated test case for my nodejs application using mocha testing framework.
2. And i encountered a test case which i need to restart my nodejs application to get the most updated configuration. ( Its the configuration for BACnet device's setting such as UDP port and instance number )
3. So i write a test case to change the UDP port. But the UDP port will only take effect after reintialization of the nodejs application.

## What i had tried ( restart processs, i get it from SO )

```
setTimeout( () => 
            {
                process.on("exit", function () 
                {
                    require( "child_process" ).spawn(process.argv.shift(), process.argv, 
                    {
                        cwd: process.cwd(),
                        detached : true,
                        stdio: "inherit"
                    });
                });

                process.exit();
            }, 1000);
```

Comment: what happens when you use that code?

Comment: You could use something like `pm2` or `nodemon` to restart your nodejs application when it exits

Comment: When i use that code it will restart the process which included mocha. That is why I dont want to exit the process, if i exit the process my mocha test will be reloaded too. I want to exit the nodejs part only not the mocha test part. Because after exit Node.js application and restart nodejs application then i want to continue my subsequent test cases.

Comment: oh, sounds complicated - can't help